# Can one upgrade to a next class using American award miles on other One world airlines?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, american-airlines, qatar-airways, upgrades

I have 67,607 award miles on AA and I am planning to purchase an economy ticket on Qatar Airways for my upcoming travel. Can I use my award miles to buy an upgrade to the Q Suite (Business class) on Qatar? Is it possible?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question per se, but an award ticket from the US to Asia on QR costs only 70,000 AAdvantage miles, so why don't you just buy the extra miles you need and then use them for a business class ticket?

Comment: Well, my question was if I can just upgrade an economy ticket to business using AA miles which I cannot. As you said, I can buy the extra miles and get a business class ticket directly but I don’t want to do that and that’s not my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One cannot upgrade using the AA miles on Qatar Airways to the next class. You can upgrade using Q miles if you have any. I found it in person when I took the flight two days ago.